# Table named 'Index'

Tags: mysql

I have a table named 'Index'. I realize that this is a keyword in MySQL, and was wondering how I can reference this table in queries?

My error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Index' (ID) )' at line 9
```

Comment: The guys will tell you that back ticks will work - BUT your really should change the table name and avoid reserved keywords (and spaces or special characters in table names)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use backticks:

```
references `Index` (ID)
```

You actually already did this when you created the `Index` table (and you must have used backticks or else you could not have created the table):

```
CREATE TABLE `Index`
```

You should avoid naming databases, tables, and columns using MySQL keywords.

Comment: Keywords like `index` AND `grants`; though at least `grants` isn't "reserved".

Answer (score 0):

you can use backticks instead of quotes

```
CONSTRAINT grants_fk_index
    FOREIGN KEY (Index_fk)
    references `Index` (ID)
```